# System.IO Namespace in Azure File Storage

Tags: c#, file, azure

Basically, I have mapped an Azure File Storage as network device and managed to get the following code to work:

```
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]ConfiguratorApi configuratorApi)
{
    string SourcePath = "Z:\\Skeleton";
    string DestinationPath = "Z:\\TMP";
    return GenerateConfigFiles(configuratorApi, SourcePath, DestinationPath);
}
```

What this GenerateConfigFiles actually does is coping from the skeleton to tmp folder a certain files and editing some of them(using System.IO), according to the input. What I want to achieve is to deploy the app in Azure as App Service (not VM) and continue using the System.IO. I've tried something like this:

```
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]ConfiguratorApi configuratorApi)
{

    CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("config");
    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
    CloudFileDirectory skeletonDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("Skeleton");
    CloudFileDirectory newConfigDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("TMP");


    string SourcePath = skeletonDir.Uri.ToString(); 
    string DestinationPath = newConfigDir.Uri.ToString(); 
    return GenerateConfigFiles(configuratorApi, SourcePath, DestinationPath);
}
```

and out of that I get

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

because the paths are like

> https://mystoragename.file.core.windows.net/config/Skeleton

Moreover, I went through the web, but most of the posts are fairly old and not relevant anymore. Is this possible at all(maybe by SAS - shared access signature) or I am going in totally wrong direction?
I am also open for other solutions.

The folders are not larger than 2MB.

Comment: If your folders are given as URLs then I'd have thought you have to interact with them via HTTP requests, especially if you're in an app service context which I would guess has no ability to map drive letters. Alternatively you might be able to use the SMB address (\\server\share) which you used when mapping the drive directly from the app service (rather than the drive letter). But the docs show you how you can use that CloudFileClient to programatically manipulate the filesystem - basically it's a wrapper round the necessary HTTP requests.

Comment: e.g. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I went through the docs, before posting the question, but still don't understand a lot of stuff. That's why I am asking for someone with previous experience. Moreover, right now I am trying to setup a SAS to see if it's going to help.

Comment: So far, I managed to run it locally, the problem was that the url must not content the protocol in the beginning, so it should be like "//mystoragename.file.core.windows.net/config/Skeleton", but now when I deploy it I get UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\mystoragename.file.core.windows.net\config\Skeleton' is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the `GenerateConfigFiles` method is used to copy files based on the path of file system. For hosting your application on Azure Web App, I assume that you could not mount your Azure File share. But you could leverage the [storage client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) to download files from your share to the temp folder of your web app, then process the files as you need, then save back to your share. For the available directory access under azure web app, you could follow the **File System Restrictions/Considerations** section under [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Or you need to host your application to azure cloud service or azure VM, then [Mount an Azure File share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! What if I just use the temp folder as storage, is it considered as a bad practice ?

Comment: The files store under the local directory may not be persisted and these files may be removed if you restart your web app. Also, they are not shared among multiple instances of your web app. Details you could follow [Understanding the Azure App Service file system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system).

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to achieve it exactly using the temp folder.